# JavaScript: get array of day names of given date (month/year)

Tags: javascript, date

how can i get the whole month in day namesof given month/year?
like :

```
var year = "2000";
var month = "7"

... some code here that makes an array with names of days of the given month...
```

and the output looks something like:

```
Array ("1. Sunday", "2. Monday", "3. Tuesday", ... "29. Thursday", "30. Friday", "31. Saturday");
```

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: This isn't so much a "JavaScript" question as it is a "which date API do I want to use" question. The JavaScript part is easy as pie once you've found an API that will determine which days of the week fell in a particular month of a particular year.

Comment: What output are you expecting for this date.Saturday?

Comment: Scratch that... shouldn't be too hard at all... not thinking clearly this late :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do what you asked.

```
function getDaysArray(year, month) {
    var numDaysInMonth, daysInWeek, daysIndex, index, i, l, daysArray;

    numDaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    daysIndex = { 'Sun': 0, 'Mon': 1, 'Tue': 2, 'Wed': 3, 'Thu': 4, 'Fri': 5, 'Sat': 6 };
    index = daysIndex[(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).toString().split(' ')[0]];
    daysArray = [];

    for (i = 0, l = numDaysInMonth[month - 1]; i < l; i++) {
        daysArray.push((i + 1) + '. ' + daysInWeek[index++]);
        if (index == 7) index = 0;
    }

    return daysArray;
}
```

Comment: If you want me to add comments to explain what I'm doing at each step, just let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: h @natlee75 suppose that i want to assign "4 peole names" in every day of the month from people array extracted randomly what is the right path to achieve this? In other hand create an automagic woks shift for entire month from worker array.
Thanks for possible answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to display todays day of the week.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

function myFunction()
{var b=[],weekday = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],month=7,year=2000;
for(var i=1,l=daysInMonth(month,year);i<l;i++){
var d = new Date(year,month-1,i);
b.push(i+"."+weekday[d.getDay()]);
}
console.log(b);}//b is the desired array
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be noted that in your `myFunction()`, `month` is 1-based, not zero-based; that is the only way your implementation of `daysInMonth` will work properly. This may cause confusion as javascript's `Date` object uses a zero-based month value

Comment: No, month is zero-based. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/

Comment: Also, using `new Array` for your `weekday` array is inefficient, you're better off doing `weekday = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']`. Also, there's no need to recreate the array in every iteration of your `for` loop.

Comment: @Random - Invoking `daysInMonth` during each iteration of your `for` loop is highly inefficient. Something along the lines of `for (var i = 1, l = daysInMonth(month, year); i < l; i++)` is better because the code in the second "segment" of a `for` loop is invoked for every iteration through the loop.

Comment: @Random - jackwanders is correct about the `new Array` call. It's strange that you used that there since you initialized `b` the proper way only a few lines above. Defining the whole array right from the start is the most efficient way, but even declaring an empty array and then pushing each day of the week into it would have been more efficient.

Comment: @Random - Since you already know the year, month and day (i) you could skip the string creation in `month+"/"+i+"/"+year` and just pass the three values into the `Date` constructor: `Date(year, month, i)`. In any case you should subtract 1 from `month` since month is zero-based (so July would be 6, not 7).

Answer (score 0):

[DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) has the functions you need to implement the logic:

- [`getDaysInMonth(year, month)`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#getDaysInMonth)
- [`date.toString("dddd")`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers)

As @natlee75 noted, you can handle the logic from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the logic yourself pretty easily using the standard JavaScript Date object.  Here's an example of getting one date to push into your array.  Just loop through the entire month calling the method. ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cL4E9/))

```
var daysOfTheWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

function getDisplay(month, day, year) {
    var d = new Date(year, month-1, day);
    return day + '. ' + daysOfTheWeek[d.getDay()];
}

array_push($dates, getDisplay(7, 4, 2012));
```

Comment: i think there should be `month+1`

Comment: No, month is zero based. January is zero.  That's why I swapped it in that function to correspond with his variables.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/

Comment: that;s why if user input July (`7`) then java script should interpreted it as `6`

Comment: Yeah, that's why I subtract 1 from the month in getDisplay().

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see the result in console.

```
<script>
var weekday = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
               'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var month = '7';
var year = '2012';
realMonth = parseInt(month,10)-1;
var monthObj = {};
for(var i=1;i<30;i++)
{
    var d = new Date(year,realMonth,i);              
    monthObj[i] = weekday[d.getDay()];
}
console.log(monthObj);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but today a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59249724/5980430) linked to this, and I'd like to point out one don't really need to do much things other than convert `day (0-6)` to `string (Sunday-Saturday)`

```js
function getDays(year, month) { //month: 1-based, as normal person
    --month //change it to 0-based, as Date object
    let dayname = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
    let date = new Date(year, month)
    let result = []
    while(date.getMonth()==month){
      result.push(`${date.getDate()}. ${dayname[date.getDay()]}`)
      date.setDate(date.getDate()+1)
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getDays(2019,12))
```