# Loop throught list in circle and fill in table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I give my best to explain it as clear as possible, because it's hard to explain, what I exactly try to do:

I've got this list of names:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "Robinson"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Walker"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Henderson"
        }
}
```

In this list I can select the name, where I would start my loop (below I explain how).

Now I need to loop a table like in this attachement:

[image]

So I loop the list for the current month (for example "December" of this year). In the first table-row, I start with the first date (1), the first day of this month (in this example this would be "Thursday") and then in the next three table-data I loop the names, starting with my selected name (in this example it would be "Walker", so the second item of my list". Than I loop throught the list till the end of the month (walker -> henderson -> robinson -> walker etc. till the last day of the month). I also have to check, it the day of the current looped table-row is a Sunday, and skip this table row and fill it with "Sunday" and go on on the next table-row. So I have to loop the exact days of a monts (1-30, 1-31 or february 1-28/29), loop the current days (Monday - Sunday) and loop the list in a circle beginning with my selected item till the end of the month with escaping Sundays. I havn't got an idea how to do this. I would like to do this with `ng-repeat`. Has someone got an idea? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

It should also work, it I have more than 3 items in my list for example:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "Robinson"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Walker"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Henderson"
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "Cole"
        }
}
```

So it should loop like this, if my start item is "Walker":

**Row 1 ->** 1 - Thursday - Walker - Henderson - Cole

**Row 2 ->** 2 - Friday - Robinson - Walker - Henderson

**Row 3 ->** 3 - Saturday - Cole - Robinson - Walker

**Row 4 ->** 4 - Sunday - Sunday - Sunday - Sunday

**Row 5 ->** 5 - Monday - Henderson - Cole - Robinson

And so on... At the moment, when my list is longer than 3 items, the repeat shows all items in the same row so it looks like this:

**Row 1 ->** 1 - Thursday - Walker - Henderson - Cole - Robinson

**Row 2 ->** 2 - Friday- Walker - Henderson - Cole - Robinson

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some JS to get the days in a given month and parse into an array, then feed that to ng-repeat. [**Example plunker.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TFwa5bjkWYOFXgbtQ8nc)

I borrowed some code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322281/javascript-get-array-of-day-names-of-given-date-month-year). In your view, something like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <select ng-model="selected" ng-change="shuffle(selected)">
    <option ng-repeat="i in menuItems" value="{{i.Name}}">{{i.Name}}</option>
  </select>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>07:00-12:00</th>
      <th>12:00-17:00</th>
      <th>17:00-22:00</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="n in month">
      <td>{{n.date}}</td>
      <td>{{n.day}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="name in items">{{n.day !== "Sunday" ? name : n.day}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

In your controller, something like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.menuItems = [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "Robinson"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Walker"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Henderson"
        }];

  $scope.month = getDaysArray(2016, 12);
  $scope.items = ["Robinson", "Walker", "Henderson"];
  $scope.shuffle = function(selected) {
    let index = $scope.items.indexOf(selected);
    for (let i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
      if (i < index) $scope.items.push($scope.items.shift());
    }
  }

});

function getDaysArray(year, month) {
    var numDaysInMonth, daysInWeek, daysIndex, index, i, l, daysArray;

    numDaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    daysIndex = { 'Sun': 0, 'Mon': 1, 'Tue': 2, 'Wed': 3, 'Thu': 4, 'Fri': 5, 'Sat': 6 };
    index = daysIndex[(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).toString().split(' ')[0]];
    daysArray = [];

    for (i = 0, l = numDaysInMonth[month - 1]; i < l; i++) {
        let n = {date: (i+ 1), day: daysInWeek[index++]};
        daysArray.push(n);
        if (index == 7) index = 0;
    }

    return daysArray;
}
```

Comment: Hi and first thanks for this nice answer. It works fine to create the correct days of an month and to skip the sunday like I asked. But how can a loop the items (list of names) in a circle, when I select my first one. So imagine, in your solution would be a dropdown with the namse of the items (Robinson, Walker, Henderson) and I pick "Walker" as starting name for the loop, so the loop would start with "Walker", then the next would be "Henderson" and the next woulbe be "Robinson" (because after the last item the first comes again). How can I do this? I hope this is clear enough..

Comment: Ok, see updates. We have a separate menu which contains the selectable items, and an array called items which we can mutate. When the menu is selected, we simply pull the first item off the array and put it on the back until we've reached the selected item. We use ng-repeat twice, once for the days  of month and once for the table. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I looked for, thank you very much!

Comment: But I have got still a question: When my items have more than 3 indexes (for example 5 names), it seems not working like expected? Can you check this please? Thanks

Comment: So it should break the ng-repeat after every third item into a new line...