# Javascript Skip saturday and sunday looping in month

Tags: javascript

I need to create an array of objects connected to each day of the month excluding weekends.
example: 
Monday -1, Tuesday-2, Wednesday-3, Thursday-4, Friday-5,
Monday-8 and so on. // jump two days

I found this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11322513/1273715) very useful for my idea...

code:

```js
function getDaysArray(year, month) {
  var numDaysInMonth, daysInWeek, daysIndex, index, i, l, daysArray;

  numDaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  daysIndex = {
    'Sun': 0,
    'Mon': 1,
    'Tue': 2,
    'Wed': 3,
    'Thu': 4,
    'Fri': 5,
    'Sat': 6
  };
  index = daysIndex[(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).toString().split(' ')[0]];
  daysArray = [];

  for (i = 0, l = numDaysInMonth[month - 1]; i < l; i++) {
    if (daysInWeek[index++] == "Sunday" || daysInWeek[index++] == "Saturday") {
      continue; //I tried: no success.
    }
    daysArray.push({
      "title": "Turn",
      "resourceid": "4",
      "start": year + "-" + month + "-" + (i + 1) + "+" + "08:00:00",
      "end": year + "-" + month + "-" + (i + 1) + "+" + "14:00:00",
      "internals": ground[i] // people from array to assign at specific date
    });

    if (index == 7) index = 0;
  }

  return daysArray;
}
console.log(getDaysArray(2019, 12));
```

Comment: what is `ground`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier: just use your `index` variable. If it equals 0 or 6, then it's a weekend, so don't push the day.

```js
function getDaysArray(year, month) {
    var numDaysInMonth, daysInWeek, daysIndex, index, i, l, daysArray;

    numDaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    daysIndex = { 'Sun': 0, 'Mon': 1, 'Tue': 2, 'Wed': 3, 'Thu': 4, 'Fri': 5, 'Sat': 6 };
    index = daysIndex[(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).toString().split(' ')[0]];
    daysArray = [];

    for (i = 0, l = numDaysInMonth[month - 1]; i < l; i++) {
     if (index != 0 && index != 6) {
           daysArray.push({
                "title":"Turn",
                "resourceid":"4",
                "start":year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1)+"+"+"08:00:00",
                "end":year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1)+"+"+"14:00:00"
            });
      }
      
      index++;

      if (index == 7) index = 0;
    }

    return daysArray;
}
    
console.log(getDaysArray(2019, 12));
```

Comment: Thank U Francois, easy, elegant and verbose. I tried this way bat index don't ouput in consolle. You have added index++; this is what I didn't think of, because of if index = 7 index = 0.
 Believing that the index increased with every spin and it was enough console.log (index) to intercept index ... bat not.
  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following condition

```
 if(daysInWeek[(new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1))).getDay()]!='Sunday'&&daysInWeek[(new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1))).getDay()]!= 'Saturday')
```

So, The Code would be following.

```
  function getDaysArray(year, month) {
   var numDaysInMonth, daysInWeek, daysIndex, index, i, l, daysArray;

numDaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
daysIndex = { 'Sun': 0, 'Mon': 1, 'Tue': 2, 'Wed': 3, 'Thu': 4, 'Fri': 5, 'Sat': 6 };
index = daysIndex[(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).toString().split(' ')[0]];
daysArray = [];

for (i = 0, l = numDaysInMonth[month - 1]; i < l; i++) {
if(daysInWeek[(new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1))).getDay()]!=  'Sunday' &&       daysInWeek[(new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1))).getDay()]!=  'Saturday')   
daysArray.push({
            "title":"Turn",
            "resourceid":"4",

            "start":year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1)+"+"+"08:00:00",
            "end":year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1)+"+"+"14:00:00",
            "internals": 'Asim' // people from array to assign at specific date
        });

    if (index == 7) index = 0;
}

   return daysArray;
  }
   console.log(getDaysArray(2019, 12));
```

Comment: Another answer elegant and easy to understand. But i can vote only for one. I am sorry. But tank you a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
  function getDaysArray(year, month) {
    var numDaysInMonth, daysInWeek, daysIndex, index, i, l, daysArray;
    let cnt = -1;
    numDaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    daysIndex = { 'Sun': 0, 'Mon': 1, 'Tue': 2, 'Wed': 3, 'Thu': 4, 'Fri': 5, 'Sat': 6 };
    index = daysIndex[(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).toString().split(' ')[0]];
    daysArray = [];

    for (i = 0, l = numDaysInMonth[month - 1]; i < l; i++) {
      if (daysInWeek[index] == "Sunday" || daysInWeek[index] == "Saturday") {
        index++
        cnt++
        if (index == 7) index = 0;
        continue
      }
      if (cnt == -1) {
        cnt = 0;
      }
      daysArray.push((cnt + 1) + '. ' + daysInWeek[index++]);
      cnt++;
      if (index == 7) index = 0;
    }

    return daysArray;
  }
  console.log(getDaysArray(2019, 12));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build date using the Date() contructor and then use the getDay() method to check if it is satuday(6) or sunday(0).

```
function getDaysArray(year, month) {
var numDaysInMonth, daysInWeek, daysIndex, index, i, l, daysArray;

  numDaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  daysIndex = { 'Sun': 0, 'Mon': 1, 'Tue': 2, 'Wed': 3, 'Thu': 4, 'Fri': 5, 'Sat': 6 };
  index = daysIndex[(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).toString().split(' ')[0]];
  daysArray = [];

  for (i = 0, l = numDaysInMonth[month - 1]; i < l; i++) {
    var d=new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1))
     if(!(d.getDay()==0 || d.getDay()==6)){
      console.log(d)
       daysArray.push({
            "title":"Turn",
            "resourceid":"4",
            "start":year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1)+"+"+"08:00:00",
            "end":year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1)+"+"+"14:00:00",
            "internals": ground[i] // people from array to assign at specific date
        });
  }
    if (index == 7) index = 0;
 }
    return daysArray;
}
 console.log(getDaysArray(2019, 12));
```

Comment: `year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1)` you don't need to do this. the constructor is overloaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax

Comment: Thank you Honey and wellcome. I need "year+"-"+month+"-"+(i + 1)" for creating fullcalendar events. And the output is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a date for the first and last day of the month and then loop through all the days while incrementing the date by one day on every iteration and checking whether the current day is Saturday or Sunday by calling `.getDay()`.

> **Date.prototype.getDay()**
>
> Returns the day of the week (0-6) for the specified date according to local time.

0 and 6 represent Sunday and Saturday respectively.

---

Here is the code:

```js
function getDaysArray(year, month) {
  let currDate = new Date(year, month-1, 1);
  let lastDate = new Date(year, month, 0);
  let lastDay = lastDate.getDate();
  let daysArray = [];
  
  for(let i=1; i < lastDay+1; i++) {
    if (currDate.getDay() != 0 && currDate.getDay() != 6) {  // Sunday and Saturday are 0 and 6 respectively
      daysArray.push({
        "title": "Turn",
        "resourceid": "4",
        "start": year + "-" + month + "-" + i + "+" + "08:00:00",
        "end": year + "-" + month + "-" + i + "+" + "14:00:00",
        "internals": "placeholder" // ground[i-1] // people from array to assign at specific date
      });
    }
    currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return daysArray;
}

// example call for December 2019
console.log( getDaysArray(2019, 12) );
```

Comment: @sundsx Edited to change `ground[i]` to `ground[i-1] `, since `i` starts from 1 in my solution. Should work perfectly.

Comment: @sundsx I added `let daysArray = [];` and I commented out `ground[i-1]` so you can run the test here.